# Why tracepath and chrome use different gateway

Tags: arch-linux, vpn, chrome, traceroute

System: Archlinux latest

Softerware: NetworkManager

My route table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.3.0.9        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 tun0
1.0.1.0         192.168.2.1     255.255.255.0   UG    5      0        0 enp0s26u1u3
1.0.2.0         192.168.2.1     255.255.254.0   UG    5      0        0 enp0s26u1u3
1.0.8.0         192.168.2.1     255.255.248.0   UG    5      0        0 enp0s26u1u3
1.0.32.0        192.168.2.1     255.255.224.0   UG    5      0        0 enp0s26u1u3
1.1.0.0         192.168.2.1     255.255.255.0   UG    5      0        0 enp0s26u1u3
1.1.2.0         192.168.2.1     255.255.254.0   UG    5      0        0 enp0s26u1u3
1.1.4.0         192.168.2.1     255.255.252.0   UG    5      0        0 enp0s26u1u3
```

I connect to a vpn in USA (I am living in China myself). And add some ip range by using

`route add xxx.xxx.xxx.0/13 via 192.168.2.1 metric 5`

Then I tracepath an Chinese website: http://taobao.com

```
$ tracepath taobao.com                                                      
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.2.1                                           4.209ms 
 1:  192.168.2.1                                           3.692ms 
 2:  no reply
 3:  183.128.112.175                                       9.918ms pmtu 1492
 3:  183.128.112.1                                         8.514ms 
 4:  61.164.22.98                                         10.032ms asymm  5 
 5:  61.130.126.22                                        11.133ms asymm  6 
 6:  183.136.160.150                                      14.151ms 
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
```

It goes the gateway expected (my router ip).

But When I visit taobao.com

> It's very slow and the site says I am in America.

What's the difference between `tracepath` and `chrome`? Can I make chrome use the default gateway?

Comment: How does `xxx.xxx.xxx.0` relate to the other IPs involved? What VPN software are you using and how is it configured (there are several levels at which a VPN can work, some might affect web traffic but not `tracepath`)? Which gateway is the default gateway — the VPN or the local one?

Comment: @Gilles The default gateway is the vpn connection. I add some ip range to the local connection. By the way I am using NetworkManager to manage vpn